# sublist parameters are not supported in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sublist parameter is not supported.
and here is the code

```
def calcEuclideanDist((x1, y1),(x2,y2)):
    dist = float(((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5)
    return dist
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: that is actually some neat syntactic sugar option, let's make it a feature request :P

Comment: That's correct. This feature is not supported in Python. However, you need to phrase a question if you want to get a useful response from the community. What is your question in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't define function's arguments as elements of tuple.

Please try instead:

```
def calcEuclideanDist(p1,p2):
    # p1, p2 are tuples with at least 2 elements each
    dist = float(((p2[0]-p1[0])**2 + (p2[1]-p1[1])**2)**0.5)
    return dist


print(calcEuclideanDist((1,2),(3,4))) # output: 2.8284271247461903
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calcEuclideanDist(x1, y1,x2,y2):
    dist = float(((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5)
    return dist

x=calcEuclideanDist(1,2,2,3)
print(x)
```

"((x1, y1),(x2,y2))" remove these nested circular brackets

Answer (score 0):

to simulate this, you can either have 4 params and use [`* unpacking`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) when calling the function,
or accept 2 tuples and unpack them at the start of the function.
*(both options don't look as nice as your original code...)*

```py
def calcEuclideanDist4(x1, y1,x2,y2):
    dist = float(((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5)
    return dist

def calcEuclideanDist2(p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    dist = float(((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5)
    return dist


p1 = (0,0)
p2 = (3,4)

print(calcEuclideanDist4(*p1,*p2))
print(calcEuclideanDist2(p1,p2))
```

Output:

```
5.0
5.0
```